# Why is my Emacs Theme change Incomplete

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to change my Emacs theme. I'm using iTerm2, and I wonder if that is the culprit of this problem. The theme I wanted to try out is Zenburn, however, after configuring `~/.emacs` file, my Emacs still looks very different to the screenshot took here: http://emacsthemes.caisah.info/zenburn-theme/ [image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

The background color did not change, and the line separates line number and actual code is too obvious. Any reason why this would happen and how to fully apply Zenburn theme?

Comment: You might want to inform us how you acquired the theme and how you are trying to use it?

Comment: Maybe, this is because you use Emacs in a terminal window. My guess is that Emacs renders plain text using the default text of the terminal, and likewise for the background. In addition, Emacs is (most likely) restricted to the 256 ANSI colors, so there might be a discrepancy between the colors used in a real Emacs frame and the terminal frame.

Comment: @Lindydancer that could be the problem but I already did `export TERM = xterm-256`

Comment: @WindDweller, it should actually be `TERM=xterm-256color`. However, even with 256 colors, it's hard to get the exact nuance of the full 24 bit color range a real Emacs frame has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to me is your background looks like that of Solarized dark theme. It may have happened that you have initialized that theme earlier. It might be the case that you have compiled that `.emacs` file to byte code but your newer change is not. Open `.emacs` in Emacs editor and try `M-x eval-buffer`. Your configuration looks fine to me. If that works then either you will need to remove `.emacs.elc` or do a byte compilation for your `.emacs`.

Comment: Funny enough, Solarized Dark Theme is the theme to my iTerm2 terminal (https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized). Once I turned off that theme, I get the full zen-burn effect.